# Tucker Nearness Problem

Tags: optimization, tensors, karush-kuhn-tucker

I'm still not very confident with tensor calculus and I came across a paper that was solving an optimization problem based on Tucker decomposition; I don't understand how, from the initial formulation, it ends up in a simplified optimization problem with respect to each-mode basis matrix.

Let $\pmb Y \in R^{I_1 \times I_2  \times I_3}$ a 3D-tensor, $\pmb G \in R^M_1 \times M_2 \times I_3$ the core tensor and $A \in R^{I_1 \times M_1} B \in R^{I_2 \times M_2}$

The initial formulation is 
$$ min_{(A,B,\pmb G)} ||\pmb Y - \pmb G \times_1 A \times_2 B ||_F^2 $$ 
subject to $ A^TA=I_{M_1}, B^TB=I_{M_2}$

The paper says "substituting one of the KKT conditions $ \pmb G= \pmb Y \times_1 A^T \times_2 B^T $ we can obtain a problem wrt each mode".

Defining $X_A:= [\pmb Y \times_2 B^T ]_{(1)} \in R^{I_1 \times M_2I_3}$ and $X_B:= [\pmb Y \times_1 A^T ]_{(2)} \in R^{I_2 \times M_1I_3}$ the problem becomes

$$min_{A} ||X_A - AA^TX_A ||_F^2 \quad AA^T=I_{M_1}$$
$$min_{B} ||X_B - BB^TX_B ||_F^2 \quad BB^T=I_{M_2}$$

I stopped to the point where I can write the initial formulation as:
 $$ min_{(A,B)} ||\pmb Y - \pmb Y \times_1 A A^T \times_2 BB^T ||_F^2 $$

Thank you in advance

Comment: could you add a link to the original paper you are reading?

Comment: Page 4 
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/274899434_Linked_Tucker2_Decomposition_for_Flexible_Multi-block_Data_Analysis